# LM2576 unload state

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

I've seen something weird with the LM2576 diode waveform when I leave it without load and with the load. Here is the diode waveform when I put a 100ohm resistor as LM2576's load.
[image]
[image]

It seems the circuit and diode works fine. However, By removing the load I see this diode waveform:
[image]

I need to know why oscillation has been occured during the off time and where it comes from.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With no load, the operation of the switcher enters DCM (discontinuous conduction mode) where all the inductor's stored energy that can be fed to the output is transferred. The remaining (unusable) energy circulates round the MOSFET's parasitic drain-source capacitance and forms a resonant circuit with the inductor. This produces a decaying sinewave as seen on your 2nd oscilloscope screen shot: -

[image]

It's pretty normal so, no need to worry.

Comment: Thank you very much, Andy, Could you provide me with a good reference that explains this phenomenon with more detail?

Comment: @JohnJin I'm afraid I can't. It's been decades since I learnt this and anyway, there is always good stuff to be found on the internet. When anyone asks me I honestly can never recommend any book (neither do I read any) - I learn everything on-line now and can never remember where I learnt things.

Comment: I appreciate your help. Thank you.